# What does AWS ECS exception Container.image contains invalid char means?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-ecs

We use CircleCi in our workflow in order to deploy PHP site as docker image on ElasticBeanstalk server. 
The `build` jobs in CircleCi is defined as follows:

```
deploy:
    docker:
      - image: docker:17.05.0-ce-git
    steps:
      - checkout
      - setup_remote_docker
      - run:
          name: Install dependencies
          command: |
            apk add --no-cache \
              py-pip=9.0.0-r1
            pip install \
              awscli \
              awsebcli --upgrade
      - run:
          name: Login to AWS
          command: |
            login="$(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-west-2)"
            ${login}
      - run:
          name: Deploy to Elastic Beanstalk
          command: |
            echo "Commit sha: ${CIRCLE_SHA1}"
            if [ "${CIRCLE_BRANCH}" == "docker" ]; then
              sed -i'' -e "s/%BUILD_NUM%/${CIRCLE_SHA1}/g" Dockerrun.aws.json
              eb deploy sales-web -l $CIRCLE_SHA1
            fi
```

In Dockerrun.aws.json under `containerDefinitions` we have (#### are correct values for application id and repository name in ECS)

```
{
            "essential": true,
            "image": "####.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/####:%BUILD_NUM%",
            "memory": 2048,
            "name": "web-container",
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "containerPort": 80,
                    "hostPort": 80
                }
            ]
        }
```

The **Login to AWS** step is successful and image is uploaded, the environment `sales-web` starts to update but fails

```
2018-03-02 16:10:41 UTC+0200    ERROR   Failed to deploy application.
2018-03-02 16:10:41 UTC+0200    ERROR   Service:AmazonECS, Code:ClientException, Message:Container.image contains invalid characters., Class:com.amazonaws.services.ecs.model.ClientException
2018-03-02 16:09:52 UTC+0200    INFO    Environment update is starting.
```

We have made sure that image is built correctly ( we can upload it ti CircleCi server, start the container and run phpunit tests). There is .elasticbeanstalk folder in root directory of project with valid `config.yml` file.

Have tried and googled for 2 days with no luck.
Will appreciate any help or guidence to understand what this error message means. If any additional details are neccessary I will provide them, just ask.

Comment: Can you check whether "####.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/####:%BUILD_NUM%" has any non-ASCII? For example, although the colon looks like a colon, is it really a colon? I've run into this problem before after copying text from tools like MS Word/Outlook.

Comment: I also had the same problem with Cloudformation. I forgot to set variable substitution right. So please beware of missing "$"-sign like this:
`Image: !Sub "${EcrUrl}/${EcrRepository}:{EcrTag}"`

Answer (score 3):

I got this using terraform when I had an extra `}` at the end of one of my variables.

What you might try doing is to construct the image name in docker, and echo it for auditing.

Update your `Dockerrun.aws.json` to be like:

```
...
"image": "%IMAGE_NAME",
...
```

and then update your circle build to be like:

```
  - run:
      name: Deploy to Elastic Beanstalk
      command: |
        echo "Commit sha: ${CIRCLE_SHA1}"
        if [ "${CIRCLE_BRANCH}" == "docker" ]; then
          IMAGE_NAME=####.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/####:${CIRCLE_SHA1}
          echo "IMAGE_NAME is $IMAGE_NAME"
          sed -i'' -e "s/%IMAGE_NAME%/${IMAGE_NAME}/g" Dockerrun.aws.json
          eb deploy sales-web -l $CIRCLE_SHA1
        fi
```

Then if it fails, copy the IMAGE_NAME output during the build and try pulling the image yourself with

```
$(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-west-2)
docker pull <IMAGE_NAME>
```

I am betting it will have an error that you can troubleshoot.

Comment: Similarly, I got this error when I was missing '$' in front of '{'. Like this:

"image": "{KIBANA_IMAGE}",

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error returned when trying to deploy with Dockerrun.aws.json. For my case I had a space in the image name attribute as shown below. Make sure your Dockerrun.aws.json file is defined correctly

```
{
    "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
    "volumes": [
      {
        "name": "demo-app",
        "host": {
          "sourcePath": "/var/app/current/demo-app"
        }
      }
    ],
    "containerDefinitions": [
      {
        "name": "demo-app",
        "image": " foo.dkr.ecr.me-south-1.amazonaws.com/foo:latest",
        "essential": true,
        "memory": 378,
        "links": ["redis"],
        "command": ["./entrypoint.sh"],
        "portMappings": [
          {
            "hostPort": 80,
            "containerPort": 5000
          }
        ],
  
        "mountPoints": [
          {
            "sourceVolume": "demo-app",
            "containerPath": "/src",
            "readOnly": true
          }
        ]
      },
    {
      "name": "redis",
      "image": "redis:latest",
      "essential": false,
      "memory": 128
  }
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when trying to use GitHub actions.

```
- name: Build, tag, and push image to Amazon ECR
  id: build-image
  env:
     <---- $ECR_REPOSITORY missing here since it is used below      
     ECR_REGISTRY: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}
     IMAGE_TAG: ${{ github.sha }}
  run: |
     # Build a docker container and
     # push it to ECR so that it can
     # be deployed to ECS.
     docker build -t $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG .
     docker push $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG
     echo "image=$ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
```

```
ECR_REGISTRY: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}
```

which comes from the step above it

```
 - name: Login to Amazon ECR
        id: login-ecr
        uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@v1
```